# Entity Framework failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. on foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I run the following code I get

```
try {
    var questionRepo = new QuestionRepository(db);
    var question = new Question();

    question.QuestionText = text;
    question.QuestionCategory = SelectedQuestionCategory;
    db.QuestionCategory.Attach(SelectedQuestionCategory);

    //Tried adding 
    //db.Entry(question).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

    questionRepo.Add(question);
    db.SaveChanges();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

no errors when I haven't used the `QuestionCategory` before, but I get an error if I have.

The error only shows when I already have a question with the same selected `SelectedQuestionCategory` in my database. I double checked the database and the primary key for `Question` is on an `id` column and not on `QuestionCategory`.

The error I get is:

> Attaching an entity of type 'QuestionCategory' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value.

Why is it failing on equal foreign key while the foreign key is not a combined primary key or the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be when you add Question EntityFramework tries to add another new instance of QuestionCategory to DB that attached to question.
Try to work with with Id **or** change object state of QuestionCategory.

```
question.QuestionCategory = null;
question.QuestionCategoryId = SelectedQuestionCategory.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem appears to be with the PK on QuestionCategory and not Question. How did SelectedQuestionCategory get set? Did you new() up a QuestionCategory instance with the values you wanted? If so you are inadvertently trying to add a second instance with the same PK. You might be better served to just retrieve the existing instance from db.QuestionCategory in this case since you already have the DbContext anyways.

Comment: SelectedQuestionCategory is a value seected by a drop down menu {binding} wpf.

Comment: Look into how these instances are created then and make sure that you are not tracking them already by using .AsNotTracking() when you pull them from the database.